# Laravel - ORM - Calling records

Tags: php, laravel

I have a question on which is the better way of doing things.

Controller

```
public function __construct(User $user)
{
    $this->users = $user;
    ........................
}        

public function index()
{
    $users = array();

    //I did this, cause a user class has been instantiated already in the construct function.
    $users = $this->users->all();  

    //This is what I read on the docs, static method of calling records
    $users = User::all();         
}
```

The question is which is the laravel way of doing things?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that `$users = User::all()` is the more Laravel-esque way.

I would also question the code in that constructor. You're asking the container to pass in a user (singular) then assigning it to an attribute called `$users`, plural. Seems a bit dodgy to me!

By way of example, my controller constructors typically look like this:

```
public function __construct(UserRepository $userRepository)
{
    $this->userRepository = $userRepository;
    ...
}
```

My general objective is to keep as little code as possible in the controller and get the repositories and other business objects to do the heavy lifting.

Comment: Hi @JamesG, yeah, the naming convention I did was wrong. Thanks for pointing that out. I'd really appreciate it if you'd provide some material in explaining using repositories instead of class in the constructor.  Just to add, I'm creating a middleware, and I'm in the process of cleaning up my code, and improving it to conform to MVC standards.  Thanks!

Comment: Hi @olleh - I learned my approach from Laracasts (a subscription-based tutorial site), but this article summarizes it fairly well: http://culttt.com/2013/07/08/creating-flexible-controllers-in-laravel-4-using-repositories/

Comment: Hi again @olleh - I see you are a new user to the site. If you found my answer helpful, would you mind accepting it? Thanks.

Comment: Hi @JamesG after reading the blog you've send me, I've realised that the tutorial contradicts to your answer.  Yes, you are using repositories but you haven't used the same method of using the orm in a "flexible" kind of way, as what is described in the blog.         `public function __construct(User $user)
{
  $this->user = $user;
}`    `public function index()
    {
      return $this->user->all();
    }`        Thanks for the reference though, I've learned a lot from the blog. I've struck gold in this website!

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. I just had a closer look at that code and personally I wouldn't do this: `use Cribbb\Storage\User\UserRepository as User;` because somebody reading the code who hasn't read the use statements at the top would read the code and assume that the reference to `User` is a reference to the `User` class, especially in Laravel. At the end of the day it comes down to personal preference, but my very strong preference in this instance would be to call a spade a spade and go `use Cribbb\Storage\User\UserRepository as UserRepository;` etc.

Comment: I've also read some of the comments and there are some part of the blog I dislike, especially when it was simply stated that changing to a different db(mongo) would just entail to changing the DB Repository implemented. Changes in the model relationships, would also be affected.    Good point!